# Proving by induction the explicit form of a recursive sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction

> Let  $$S(n+1)=S(n)+cb^{n+1}, n=0,1, 2 ..., c\in\mathbb{R}, b\neq 1$$
>
> Prove by induction:
>
> $$S(n)=a+c\left(\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}\right), n=0,1,2... $$

Let $p(n):S(n)=a+c\left(\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}\right) $

**First Step**

In this case I dont' now if I should prove $p(0)$ or $p(1)$ Anyway I  am not sure how do this step because I don't know $S(0)$ or $S(1)$. Can you help me please?

*Edited*

---

Is valid this?
$$S(1)=S(0)+cb$$
$$p(1)=a+c\left(\frac{b^{2}-1}{b-1}\right)=a+c(b+1)=a+c+cb$$

If $S(0)=a+c$ then $p(1) $ is true.

**Second Step**

Assume: $p(n):S(n)=a+c\left(\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}\right) $ (Induction Hypothesis)

Show:$p(n+1):S(n+1)=a+c\left(\frac{b^{n+2}-1}{b-1}\right)$

---

By definition we know that
$$ p(n+1):S(n+1)=S(n)+cb^{n+1}$$

Using the Induction Hypthosesis:
$$ p(n+1):S(n+1)=a+c\left(\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}\right)+cb^{n+1}=a+c\left(\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}+b^{n+1}\right)$$
$$p(n+1)=a+c\left(\frac{b^{n+2}-1}{b-1}\right)$$

Q.E.D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now without induction

$$
s_{n+1} = s_n + c b^{n+1}\\
s_{n} = s_{n-1} + c b^{n}\\
\cdots \\
s_0 = a
$$

then

$$
s_{n+1} = a+c\sum_{k=0}^{n}b^{k} = a+c\left(\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}\right)
$$

Inductively

First step

$$
S_0 = a+c = a+c\left(\frac{b-1}{b-1}\right)
$$

Second step

Assuming

$$
S_n = a + c\left(\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}\right)
$$

then

$$
S_{n+1} = S_n + c b^{n+1} = a + c\left(\frac{b^{n+1}-1}{b-1}\right)+c b^{n+1} = a+c\left(\frac{b^{n+2}-1}{b-1}\right)
$$

Q.E.D

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but with induction, how can I prove it?

Comment: Included the inductive demonstration.

Comment: Your "without induction" is really three inductive proofs ... you've just hidden the induction (1) by writing the sum all at once, (2) by factoring out the $c$ from the sum, and (3) by replacing the sum with the geometric-series formula.

Comment: Please illuminate us! write your play!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: With induction why $S_0=a  $ ?

Comment: You can as well, assume the first step as $S_0 = a+c$ in which case
$S_1 = S_0 + c b = a+c + c b = a+ c(b+1) = a + c\left(\frac{b^2-1}{b-1}\right)$ etc.